# Consuming WAS Service over LAN

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to WCF. I have created a service to be hosted in WAS in order to rely on TCP. The problem is that I want to create a client to host it on another computer over a LAN and I don't know how to do that. Can any one help me, please? 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial can help you:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/400697/WCF-Service-Creation-With-Csharp .
Otherwise I think we will need a more specific problem definition and some code examples of what you have right now.